# How can I resolve my "'google' is undefined" error while trying to implement a Google feed?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with Windows8 Metro Style apps and I want to implement a
Google Feed using JavaScript and HTML5, but I'm getting this error:

> "Unhandled exception at line 32, column 9 in ms-appx://f5b7d159-5dd1-4c68-b0ba-3b3403d1fe78/default.html
>
> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'google' is undefined"

I'm not able to create the Google API object using `google.load("feeds","1");`
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you are including the API line in your app then we probably need to see some code.

Answer (score 2):

Did you include the google API script in your HTML?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```